# How to disable completely Hibernate caching? (with Spring 3, Hibernate with annotations)

Tags: hibernate

My java app queries a MySQL server every 10 seconds. I manually insert a new row into a table. Hibernate can't find it.

When I manually remove a row, Hibernate shows that this row exists. I suppose that is because of Hibernate caching. Is there any way to disable it at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean the first-level cache or the second-level cache?  Having a [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) second-level cache such as [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) that caches entities that correspond to the rows in the same table that you modify manually could cause the behaviour that you describe.  The first-level cache would not cause this behaviour, and I don't think you can disable it, anyway.

To disable the Hibernate second-level cache, remove from the Hibernate configuration file, `hibernate-cfg.xml`, all lines that refer to the second-level cache.  For example:

```
<!-- Enable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
    net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
    net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>     
<property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks or your replies! Hm, it seems I don't have second - level caching, maybe to try to remove 1st level? How can I do this?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot disable the first-level cache, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943366/how-can-i-configure-hibernate-to-immediately-apply-all-saves-updates-and-delete/3946939#3946939, Spring can enable eager flushing of the first-level cache, which would effectively achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In order to "try" to disable the first-level cache, I evict it everytime an EntityManager is requested. worked for me ;)

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if( emf == null ){
            if (parameters == null) {
                emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
            } else {
                emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, parameters);
            }
        } else {
            emf.getCache().evictAll();
        }

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
hints.put("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);
in your persist method() it may work.