# Spring Data + JPA > New entries of "mappedBy" property are not fetched from DB after SQL INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa

Hej.

I think I am experiencing some odd behaviour with Spring Data, JPA and the alike. I wrote a flyway migration script that inserts new data into a table **cash_entry_note.**

Which is related to an entity `AbstractCashEntry` the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = AbstractCashEntry.TABLE_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "key", callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
abstract public class AbstractCashEntry extends TenantBaseModel {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cashEntry", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
protected Set<CashEntryNote> notes = new HashSet<>();
```

which is the super class for `CashEntry`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cash_entry")
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true, exclude = "group")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CashEntry extends AbstractCashEntry {
```

and finally the class `CashEntryNote` itself

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cash_entry_note")
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true, exclude = "cashEntry")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CashEntryNote extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private AbstractCashEntry cashEntry;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Note note;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @DiffIgnore
    private User reporter;

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return createdAt;
    }
}
```

now what I do is some plain and simple SQL inserts:

```
INSERT INTO [cash_entry_note] (created_at, modified_at, cash_entry, note, reporter) VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE(), @cash_key, @initial_note, 'username')
```

After that, I would expect the JpaRepository to return the `CashEntry` entity with the attached new notes, I just recently inserted. However, this is not the case. The property `notes` of a `CashEntry` is always an empty set or contains the notes that where already there prior to the SQL inserts. Even when trying to use FetchType.EAGER or restarting the server, the repository does not return the newly sql-inserted notes. What am I missing? Anybody got an idea?

I should also mention, that this project is using [Javers][1] http://javers.org/documentation/ to track changes in entites and provide them later on in an audit log.

Comment: Could be a caching issue. By default JPA thinks it is the only client, which means it caches very aggressively, and will not ask the database if it has already loaded all data from a given table. If you modify the data outside a persistence context, you need to disable the shared JPA cache, this can be done globally or per entity. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187344/how-to-disable-completely-hibernate-caching-with-spring-3-hibernate-with-anno. You may also want to google the JPA 2 `shared-cache-mode` option

Comment: Good point you're directing too, cheers. This also applies when the problem still persists after application restart?

Comment: When you restart the cache should be gone, unless you use are using a persisted second level cache, like EhCache.

Comment: Nah, I don't. So I guess that won't be it. Pity, thanks anyway. Currently I'm checking more into the JaVers universe to find out if the changed notes must be tracked by it to be seen in the JPARepository - even if that makes very little sense to me. You never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The `@cash_key` variable somehow contained spaces or a tab or any invisible control characters - which however did not prevent it to work in a comparison in a where clause before the insert, so that was really hard to pinpoint.

`SELECT @cash_key = min(cash_key) FROM cash_entry` is to blame here